# divs don't load correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css

SOLVED!!! SCROLL TO END OF THIS QUESTION!

As you can see [here](http://kerstlichtshow.hostingsiteforfree.com/tracks1.html):

I've made a page with all the soundtracks of the show this website's about, but when I load it, the divs in the div that create the rows aren't displayed correctly until you hover one of that divs, than that particular one looks like it has to. I don't want that my visitors have to find out how they fix it and it's just irritating, so what to do about it.

**DOM:**

```
<body>
    <div> <!--row wrapper-->
        <div class="track"> <!--track information-->
            <img src="" />        <!--album cover-->
            <h3></h3>             <!--artist-->
            <p></p>               <!--title-->
        </div> <!--/track information-->
    </div> <!--/row wrapper-->

    <div> <!--row wrapper-->
        <div class="track"> <!--track information-->
            <img src="" />        <!--album cover-->
            <h3></h3>             <!--artist-->
            <p></p>               <!--title-->
        </div> <!--/track information-->
    </div> <!--/row wrapper-->

    ...
</body>
```

**JS (jQuery):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.track').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).stop();                 //stop previous animation
            $(this).animate({height:'250'});   //expand, so title and artist will be visible.
        });
        $('div.track').mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).stop();                 //stop previous animation
            $(this).animate({height:'160px'}); //enlarge the div to it's original size
        });
    });
```

**css:**

```
<style>
    .track{
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-right: 26px;
        background-color: #a90000;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 160px;
        height: 160px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: default;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
```

---

Solved! added

css:

```
.track {
     float: left;
}
.row{
     clear: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="track"></div>
     <div class="track"></div>
     <div class="track"></div>
     <div class="track"></div>
     <div class="track"></div>
</div>
```

[result](http://kerstlichtshow.hostingsiteforfree.com/tracks3.html)

Thanx to [hungerstar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804867/hungerstar)

Comment: Add your CSS also please!

Comment: I have trouble loading your sample page

Comment: Have you tried to add `float: left` to the divs?

Comment: Your demo page doesn't load.

Comment: Yes I did try `float:left`, but than I get this http://kerstlichtshow.hostingsiteforfree.com/tracks2.html

Comment: Did you add `clear: left;` to the container DIVs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the red around each image, remove `display: inline;` from `.track`.  Or if you wan them in a row do as Pieter suggested and add `float: left;` to `.track`.  If you want all the tracks below to "push down" together, you will have to wrap some of your `.track` DIVs in another DIV and make sure that the containing DIV has `clear: left;` on it so it will start a new row.

**ADD**

```css
.track {
     float: left;
}
```

And for your containing DIVs add a class of `.row`.

```css
.row{
     clear: left;
}
```

and for your HTML

```html
<div class="row">
     <div class="track"></div>
     <div class="track"></div>
     <div class="track"></div>
     <div class="track"></div>
     <div class="track"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure the container DIVs you have for each row have `clear: left;` on them.  Otherwise they will all want to form one row and only break when they get to the edge of their container.

Comment: Glad to here it!  Cheers!

Comment: It's not yet Christmas :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left` to the divs with class `track`.

Comment: If I do that, thay won't be displayed in rows anymore, so not next to eachother.